# wpf slider thumb is changing size while moving

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

I am using a slider to show the progress of a videofile that is being played in a mediaelement. I update the position of the thumb with a timer every 200ms. I also change the position of the slider with a fast forward/fast rewind button that changes the position of the mediaelement.
the problem is that the size of the thumb changes during playing the mediaelement or when I use the forward/backward button. It gets thicker then thinner again, this is repeated. How can I fix that?

Here I uploaded a video that shows the strange behavior of the thumb
http://v7.tinypic.com/player.swf?file=2mw6xhx&s=7

---

here is the code:

**slider in xaml**

```
<Slider Name="sliderPosition" 
        Width="220" 
        Margin="2" 
        ValueChanged="sliderPosition_ValueChanged" 
        Thumb.DragStarted="sliderPosition_DragStarted"
        Thumb.DragCompleted="sliderPosition_DragCompleted" />
```

**code behind**

```
//initialization
timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200);
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();


private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MediaElem.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
    {
    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MediaElem.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds * 0.95);

    sliderPosition.Maximum = ts.TotalSeconds;
    sliderPosition.SmallChange = 1;
    sliderPosition.LargeChange = Math.Min(10, ts.Seconds / 10);

    tbPosition.Text = String.Format("00:00:00");
    tbDuration.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
    }
}


private void MoveForward(int millisec)
{
    if ((MediaElem.Position.TotalMilliseconds + millisec) > (MediaElem.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds * 0.95))
    {
        MediaElem.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MediaElem.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds * 0.95);
    }
    else
    {
        MediaElem.Position = MediaElem.Position + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisec);
        sliderPosition.Value = MediaElem.Position.TotalSeconds;
    }
}


private void MoveBackward(int millisec)
{
    if ((MediaElem.Position - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisec)) < TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0))
    {
    MediaElem.Position = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
    }
    else
    {
    MediaElem.Position = MediaElem.Position - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(millisec);
    sliderPosition.Value = MediaElem.Position.TotalSeconds;
    }
}


private void sliderPosition_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(e.NewValue);
    tbPosition.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
    MediaElem.Position = ts;
}


private void sliderPosition_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = true;
}


private void sliderPosition_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    isDragging = false;
    MediaElem.Position = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sliderPosition.Value);
}


void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!isDragging && isPlaying)
    {
    sliderPosition.Value = MediaElem.Position.TotalSeconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see the relevant pieces of code to be able to help. For example, how do you move the thumb? Is it a standard Slider control or a custom one you built?

Comment: has nobody ever experienced that problem?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem. Even without the media element (just create a slider and have a timer to increment it every N ms). The problem is less visible if incrementing full integers than doubles but it's definitely there.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely an issue with how the thumb is being drawn.   Running under Windows 7/64, the slider thumb moves horribly.  The thumb is drawn using the fancy Aero-mode theme modules and such out of the box;  So on a hunch I fired up Blend and dropped in the "SimpleSlider", which is just a regular  with a completely custom and self contained Style and Template.   Once I did this, the thumb began moving very smoothly.

You could go the route of trying the SimpleSlider style, or roll your own template from scratch.